# Euclidean realisation of a polyhedral complex

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

Let us say that an *Euclidean polyhedral manifold* is a manifold that is glued from a finite number of Euclidean polyhedrons by identifying isometrically their co-dimension $1$ faces. Let us assume that no two faces of one polyhedron are glued together and that any two polyhedrons share at most one face.

Let us say that a *topological polyhedral manifold* is the same thing but this time the faces are identified only by a diffeomorphism, and not necessarily by an isometry. Nevertheless we require that the result of gluing is a manifold.

**Question.** Suppose now we have a *topological polyhedral three manifold*. Is it always possible to choose an Euclidean structure on each of its three-dimensional faces (making these faces  Euclidean polyhedrons), so that the manifold becomes a *Euclidean polyhedral manifold*?

**Obvious remark.** The answer is yes in case of surfaces, one can just say that the surface is glued from regular polygons.

Comment: A direct dimension count seems to show that this problem is underdetermined, so you should be able to construct such a Euclidean polyhedral structure.

Comment: @ Misha I agree, it likely exists, but am afraid of that the dimension count does not suffice.

Comment: @aglearner Please clarify if you assume your Euclidean polyhedra compact or with finitely many faces. Thanks.

Comment: @agleaner Could you please give a definition of Euclidean polyhedra in you question? (Say, are all their faces topological balls? Are they convex in $\Bbb E^3$ (when equipped with an Euclidean structure)?)

Comment: For me a Euclidean polyhedron is just something diffeomorphic to a convex polyhedron in $\mathbb R^3$.